# Run a specific function on a specific field in a queryset

Tags: django

I am trying to run a function on a specific field in a queryset before i send it to the template for rendering.

I have the following models.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Device(models.Model):
    cid = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    oid = models.TextField(null=True)
```

I have the following view, that i am trying to run the checkStatus function on queryset field of oid, but everytime it runs i get the following error, the "info" is the value that the checkStatus function is returning back.

## error

```
TypeError: QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s): info.
```

## views.py

```
def device_detail(request, cid):
    customers = models.Customer.objects.all()

    customer_details = get_object_or_404(models.Customer, id=cid)
    device_details = customer_details.device_set.all()
    device_details.annotate(checkStatus("oid"))

    return render(request, 'devices/detail.html', {
        'device_details': device_details
    })
```

Comment: `annotate` is working on the datebase side, so you cannot use a python function here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of the annotate() method seems not correct. You should review the documentation about the [annotate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) method

As you have not shown the code about your function checkStatus(), I'm not sure about my advice, but I'm guessing that this should be implemented as an instance method instead of a free function. May be like this :

```py
class Device(models.Model):
    cid = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    oid = models.TextField(null=True)

    def checkStatus(self):
        if self.oid == 'something':
            return 'ok'
        return 'ko'
```

It's just an idea.

Comment: Tthats actually an excellent idea, thank you very much for that. appreciate it.